# Placing three pictures under a big picture

Tags: html, css

How to place three pictures directly under the hero picture?
It is should be look like carousel, where  you choose another pictures by clicking on another one.
Can't place them right.
Thanks!

Comment: did you try bootstrap

Comment: I am trying to use only flex or grid layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with your layout is that you used `position:absolute` for your three small images. Here is a way to do it right:

Structure your content vertically by giving your main container a `display: grid`

Each horizontal element, like the Hero, the three Images or the footer should be a single container inside of that big wrapper like that:

```html
<div class="main-wrapper">
<section>Hero</section>
<section>Images</section>
<section>Footer</section>
</div>
```

```css
.main-wrapper {
  /* Forces each element inside the wrapper to be stacked on top of each other */
  display: grid;
}

section {
 /* display flex forces the items inside each section to be display horizontally */
 max-width: 1300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
}
```

This will give you a solid base layout that you can further extend on with your special classes and styles.

I forked your codepen and gave it the basic structure I described here. You can have a look at it here: https://codepen.io/cainytheslave/pen/qBxVvyw

Comment: Thanks again @Laisender!  May I ask, how did you do it? I am trying to understand how to place elements...

Comment: Just have a look at the code, you will see what I did there. Basically both the main image and the secondary images are within one container div. Then the three secondary images are also in a own div. The outer div aligns the Main and Secondary images vertically while the inner div aligns the three secondary images horizontally. If you need some more info on Flexbox and Grid, consider looking at these resources here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/